# RBF interpolation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a matrix 5*5 I have selected few pixels as an input  (their indices and values)for the RBF I want to get the other valeus by using the RBF interpolation I've downloaded this package for that:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10056-scattered-data-interpolation-and-approximation-using-radial-base-functions

```
op=rbfcreate(indexc',value','RBFFunction', 'linear'); rbfcheck(op);  
ZI= rbfinterp(indexi, op);
```

this is what I've obtained :
Error using rbfinterp (line 13)
x should have the same number of rows as an array used to create RBF interpolation

but in my case this is impossible because the number of the unknown pixels does not equal the number of the known values.I've never used the RBF before so I don't know how do I deal with this problem.